# how do you determine which partion in dual boot pc is for ubuntu?

Tags: gparted

I am want allocate more hard drive space to Ubuntu on my lenovo ideapad, but I can't determine which partion I need to allocate the space too. Windows I know is the largest partition. [the link below will show the partitions on my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOFeF.png)

Comment: From the command line run `df -h` and that will show your partitions, where they are mounted, and how full they are.

Answer (score 1):

On the link you provided, you can see the label "Windows" on /dev/sda3, and the partition is formatted as NTFS, which are good indicators of windows being on this partition.

On the other hand, your Ubuntu system partition has the mount point "/" and is ext4 formatted, therefore is /dev/sda6.

You can then assume Windows is on sda3 and Linux on sda6.

As you Windows partition has only 55GB used over the 855GB available, you should be able to downsize it safely using Gparted, and give more room to you Ubuntu.